# Tor browser setup fails on Lubuntu 17.0.1

Tags: lubuntu, tor-browser

I've downloaded Tor Browser Bundle from https://www.torproject.org/download/download and extracted it to `/home`.

When I `cd` to `tor-browser_en-US$ start-tor-browser` and run `start-tor-browser` I get

```
command not found
```

I can see the file start-tor-browser.desktop is in the directory. If I double-click the file in File Manager I get a spinning tooltip for a few seconds and then nothing.

I've tried changing the *Permissions* property *Execute* to *Anyone*. I've deleted and re-downloaded the TBB. I also tried `sudo chmod +x start-tor-browser`, but this also gave me

```
No such file or directory
```

I've noticed tab autocomplete also doesn't pick up the file. It's as if my system can't see it.

Comment: you need to tell your OS where the file is. If you cd into the directory, you need to enter `./start-tor-browser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `./start-tor-browser.desktop` in the tor-browser directory.

As the command is not in your path, you need to prefix it with an absolute path. `.` points to current directory, so `./` effectively means file in current directory.

Comment: Thank you. Embarrassing, I thought I knew this. It works. Strange that it doesn't work using the desktop shortcut though.

Comment: The issue is *not* that `start-tor-browser.desktop` is a relative path. It is, or would be if it were interpreted as a path, but the shell does not interpret it as a path, because *command names* that don't contain `/` aren't interpreted as paths. `./start-tor-browser.desktop`, like *all* paths that start with `./`, is itself a *relative* path, and not an absolute one. An absolute path starts with `/` (though it is possible to write an absolute path in a shell that starts with something that *expands* to something else that start with `/` -- for example, `~/` expands to an absolute path).